# GridDB on Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, griddb

I need to install GridDB on an Oracle Linux 7.9 machine. There are 3 GridDB distributions, for:

1. CentOS 7.9
2. Ubuntu 18.04
3. openSUSE 15.1

I am ruling out Ubuntu as being the farthest from Oracle Linux, but hesitate between CentOS and openSUSE.

I am tending to think CentOS https://linux.oracle.com/switch/centos/

> Is this just another CentOS? Inasmuch as they're both 100%
> binary-compatible with Red Hat Enterprise Linux, yes, this is just
> like CentOS. Your applications will continue to work without any
> modification whatsoever. However, there are several important
> differences that make Oracle Linux far superior to CentOS.

Which distribution is most likely to work on Oracle Linux?
Are there any special requirements for GridDB on Oracle Linux?

GridDB documentation for CentOS
https://docs.griddb.net/latest/gettingstarted/using-rpmyum/ 
and Ubuntu
https://docs.griddb.net/latest/gettingstarted/using-apt/ 
looks good, but nothing on openSUSE

Comment: I'm a little confused, and definitely FAR from an expert, but isn't Oracle Linux a Linux Distro? What would it mean to install CentOS on Oracle Linux? Does the griddb install go into a vm on oracle linux? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Sorry, @JNevill, I was not clear. There are 3 GridDB distributions which are designed for 3 different Linux distributions, but not an Oracle Linux specific GridDB distro. I reworded the opening statement so I hope that is clear

Comment: Oh gotcha. It looks like there is a [quickstart guide on installing via RPM package](https://griddb.net/en/blog/griddb-quickstart/). Oracle Linux is based on Redhat which uses RPM, so that is likely the clearest path forward. It's no guarantee it will work, but seems like the most reasonable option. There is also installation from source which is covered in their repo's readme [here](https://github.com/griddb/griddb) although redhat isn't mentioned explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill, indeed, RPM looks like the best way to go. If you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept it and let you know the results.